# transformation of a folded piece of paper!!!

Tags: general-topology

This is a question in the book **Real Mathematical Analysis** by **Charles Chapman Pugh** and I don't know how to face it! :

Fold a piece of paper in half.

(a) Is this a continuous transformation of one rectangle into an other?

(b) Is it injective?

(c) Draw an open set in the target rectangle, and find its pre-image in the original rectangle. Is it open?

(d) What if the open set meet the crease?

the **baker's transformation** is a similar mapping. A rectangle of dough is stretched to twice its length and then folded back on itself. Is the transformation continuous? A formula for the baker's transformation in variable is $f(x)=1-|1-2x|$. then the $n^{th}$ iterate of $f$ is $f^{on}=f o f o ... o f$, n times. the **orbit** of a point x is:

${\{x,f(x), f of (x),..., f^{on}(x),...\}}$

(e) If x is rational prove that the orbit of x is finite set.

(f) If x is irrational what is the orbit?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say what your thoughts and attempts on the problem are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. *For example*, how does your definition of **continuous transformation** align with the fold-in-half transform?

Comment: Previously asked for e) *(answer attempted in question)* & f) *(not answered)*: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882986/bakers-transformation-continuity-orbits-of-irrational-and-rational-points

Comment: I do not have any idea about this question please help me

Comment: **Hint**: Let $a$ and $b$ be positive real numbers. A rectangular piece of paper can be modeled with the Cartesian rectangle
$$
[-a, a] \times [0, b] = \{(x, y) : -a \leq x \leq a, 0 \leq y \leq b\}.
$$
Fold the left half of the "paper" along the vertical midline onto the right half. If a point has Cartesian coordinates $(x, y)$ "initially", can you write down a formula for the coordinates after the folding operation? (A sketch will help. Picking specific numbers may be a good idea, as well, particularly if you don't see the formula right away.)